# Want to create web app functionality that allows a user to click download all images. Need some pointers

Tags: php, image, download

I am building a custom app for a client (a photographer for commercial real estate) using typical PHP / MySql setup.  This app will allow my client's clients to access images assigned to them, view them and download them.

I need to add the option to allow his clients to click "download all - print size quality" and "download all - web resolution".  When images are uploaded, they will automatically be saved in those separate resolutions.  To give you an idea, adding up the images a client would typically want to download, would equal up to 500MB.  I think having all the images compressed to a zip would be the way to go.

How do you suggest I approach this, and if you know any source that may help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PHP Zip](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)

example can be found here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

**OR**

If you prefer dirty solution, you can use the linux built-in [`tar`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format)) function, and combine with `exec`

---

I assume you should have 3 different dimensions for each image, and your zip is only focus on select the images with correct dimension to add into archive.

However, the above is not an issue, you should convince your clients a better way to download these huge file, like consider using a ftp program, or some download tools instead of just via http hyperlink (chances of failure is way too high)

Comment: unfortunately FTP is not an elegant solution.  the client wants his client to be able to log in via a web interface, and have access to the images under their porfolio.  you mentioned "some download tools".  could you clarify?

Comment: something like [flash get](http://download.cnet.com/FlashGet/3000-2071_4-10566273.html), where user can right-click and add into download queue, And of course, you can embed user login checking to prevent being downloaded by unverified user. )Take note on credential checking on your application)

Answer (score 1):

You should not generate a ZIP file on the fly for every download.  This would be very inefficient.

When pictures are uploaded, create two new ZIP files from the images (one for each size).  Add two columns to your table, on pointing to the smaller ZIP, and the other pointing to the larger.  Just point your two links there.

Comment: Probably right, after I re-read the question there's no picking which files to download, just download them all I'm assuming in either high res or web. +1

Comment: i was considering this route, this requires basically double the storage space on the server though. i guess that would be the only downside.  the client is thinkin about having up to 2tb of data.. so that would effectively make this 4tb.

Answer (score 0):

I would say zip would be the way to go. Using PHP to ZIP the selected files on the fly and then have the user download them automatically.

Probably having a user click checkboxes next to images in a form, the data sent to a processing page which spits out the ZIP file for the user.

this might help http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

Comment: What kind of stress does adding 500Mb of images to a zip add to a server?  I dont want the user to click download , and then have to wait 2 min before the server spits out a zip.

Comment: it's all about the outgoing bandwidth of the server connection, the server processor speed/memory in terms of how fast the files get zipeed and how much traffic you anticipate.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZipArchive](http://php.net/ZipArchive), store it to a temporary file then output it:

```
$path = '/path/to/your/images';

// search for files matching *.png; *.gif; *.jpg
$files = glob($path.'/*.{png,gif,jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);

// create temporary filename
$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'images');

// create zip
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($tmp, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // may want to manipulate $file to remove the directory prefix
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

// output as an attachment
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=foo.zip');
readfile($tmp);
```

Of course, if you really have 500MB of images, this will take a while. You're probably better off zipping your files in advance (a cron or on each upload).

Comment: When you say a while, are we talking 30 seconds.. 20 min.. 5 seconds?

Comment: You should know... It actually depends on the hardware (CPU, memory, disks) and on the server load.